# What if I don't write default in switch case?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
int a = 10;
switch(a){
case 0:
    printf("case 0");
    break;
case 1:
    printf("case 1");
    break;
}
```

Is the above code valid?

If I am sure that int `a` will not have any other value than 1 and 0, can I avoid `default`?

What if in any case a value will be different from 1 and 0?

I know this is a silly question but I was thinking that perhaps it would be illegal or undefined behavior soI just asked to make sure.

Comment: i have tried but i was thinking that perhaps it would be illegal or undefined behavior so just asked to make sure

Comment: In such cases I always put a default in and throw an exception. Now in C#7 with the greater flexibility of "case when" I've moving to covering all possible cases and using default to cover the impossible ones. Douglas Adams would understand that perspective.

Comment: I would generally add `ASSERT(false);` so that I would detect unexpected values in DEBUG builds.

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The code is valid. If there is no `default:` label and none of the `case` labels match the "switched" value, then none of the controlled compound statement will be executed. Execution will continue from the end of the switch statement.

ISO/IEC 9899:1999, section 6.8.4.2:

> [...] If no converted `case` constant expression matches and there is no `default` label, no part of the switch body is executed.

Answer (score 49):

As others have pointed out it is perfectly valid code. However, from a coding style perspective I prefer adding an empty `default` statement with a comment to make clear that I didn't unintentionally forget about it.

```
int a=10;
switch(a)
{
case 0: printf("case 0");
         break;
case 1: printf("case 1");
         break;
default: // do nothing;
         break;
}
```

The code generated with / without the `default` should be identical.

Comment: If you intend to handle all the cases in an enum, I would recommend *omitting* the default case, because most compilers will warn if an enum case is forgotten in a switch statement.

Comment: It would be even better to have an assert (or similar) if you expect it to never fall through. A lot of error can be caught this way.

Comment: @rdb Most "compilers"? Isn't it the IDE that does this?

Comment: @Kathir I wouldn't know, I don't use an IDE. These warnings are generally generated by compilers, but it is possible for the IDE to relay them to the developer. It is conceivable that some IDEs have their own code-checkers that warn the developer of this as well.

Comment: @rdb Okay. Both are possible. The compiler generating a warning during compilation. The IDE does something called [linting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/). I do not know the internals of this linting process. BUT, I don't think it compiles the code

Comment: It may be nice to have a warning about forgotten enum cases, but if the value was passed via a variable/parameter isn't it still possible that undefined values occur during run time? What about wrapping the default case between #ifndef ENUM_COVERAGE_TEST ... #endif

Answer (score 9):

It is perfectly legal code. If a is neither 0 or 1, then the switch block will be entirely skipped.

Answer (score 4):

It's valid not to have a `default` case.

However, *even if you are sure that you will not have any value rather than 1 and 0*, it's a good practice to have a default case,  to catch any other value (although it is theoretically impossible, it may appear in some circumstances, like buffer overflow) and print an error.

Comment: You are assuming that it is an error not to match one of the case statements - probably true in this case. You may _want_ to only perform an action some possible values of a variable and to just carry on in other cases. IMHO, this is a perfectly reasonable use of a switch statement.

Comment: @Charles: He wrote in the question: see if i am very much sure that int a will not have any value rather than 1 and 0 then in that case can i avoid default:

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with you, I'm sorry if it came across like that. I was just pointing out that although, in general, it is good practice to have a `default` label, it's not necessarily bad practice to omit one.

Comment: @CharlesBailey It seems very much worthwhile to include the default case if for no other reason than documenting that you at least considered the default case (even if there is no executable code therein). Given that there is relatively high benefit to including it and no real advantage from omitting it, I would say it's very good practice to include it.

Comment: @weberc2 there *is* an advantage gained from omitting it: if you are switching on an enum, some compilers will warn if an enum value is missed in the switch case.  This can be a very helpful tool to find places where a case should be added after a value is added to an enum.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the above code is valid.

If the switch condition doesn't match any condition of the case and a default is not present, the program execution goes ahead, exiting from the switch without doing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Default is not mandatory, but it always good to have it.

The code is ideally, but our life is not, and there isn't any harm in putting in a protection there. It will also help you debugging if any unexpected thing happens.

Comment: The harm is, the code needs to test for a default case before jumping to a case label. But I dont know if compilers do the test nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

It's same like no if condition is matched and else is not provided.

default is not an mandatory in switch case. If no cases are matched and default is not provided, just nothing will be executed.