# Is there a Rubocop for Scala?

Tags: scala

When I am making Rails applications, I often use [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) to help ensure my code is clean and up to par as well as readable.

I'm learning Scalatra right now and I'm wondering if there's a plugin similar to RuboCop that checks the style of your code and gives you a warning when you may be writing "dirty code". This probably isn't needed for a seasoned Scala developer, but for a beginner, this is a god send.

Comment: It's called [*lint tool*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting) and one of them is [scalastyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/)

Comment: This question would be more on-topic on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: See [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/163250) for an explanation as to why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turn on `-Xlint` in your compiler options. If you've got some spare time, also turn on `-Xfatal-warnings`. In either case, you'll learn a lot about how to write safer Scala code.

Once you've completed that exercise, set up [WartRemover](https://github.com/typelevel/wartremover), which is a *much* more opinionated linting tool. You may not agree with all the rules that ship with WartRemover—I'm not sure I do—but you'll also learn a lot by trying to follow them (and by arguing with [Brian](https://twitter.com/puffnfresh) and co. when you don't think the target of a rule is actually a wart).

There are also some syntax- and style-oriented tools like [Scalastyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/) (mentioned in the comments above) that can make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces or whatever (to be fair, Scalastyle is a little less superficial than that). These things can be useful, but I don't personally find them very interesting.

Lastly note that the best static analysis tool for Scala is `scalac` itself (even without `-Xlint` turned on). A tool like RuboCop has two main goals: to encourage you to write more idiomatic, readable code, and to try to catch problems that could happen at runtime before runtime happens. In a compiled language (especially a compiled language with a rich type system like Scala's), the compiler  itself can do a lot of the work of catching problems in your code before they crash your program at runtime.

Comment: I would say that WartRemover is for purist people (and written by purist) and likely should be considered by seasoned devs.

Comment: You could also argue that beginners in a language are _precisely_ the people who most need to be spending time hanging out with purists. Once you've got that down you'll be a lot better at deciding when to make compromises.

Answer (score 2):

Others already mentioned -Xlint, ScalaStyle, WartRemover, etc., so let me just make a bit of a general point about purism vs. non-purism.

I think what is considered "good" isn't universal, it depends on the use case. Sure it's awesome to only use vals and no vars, to write everything using beautiful tail recursions, to use monads - but tail recursions aren't always possible and you can blow a stack when the recursions can't get optimized, and even Scala's for comprehension translates to map/flatMap/foreach, which is slow compared to a while loop. For RESTful WS and other Scalatra stuff, you probably don't care about this, because I doubt you'll have deeply recursive code of your own, and Scala is so much faster than Ruby that who cares about a for comprehension vs. a while loop performance. So, I assume you can remain a purist in this context, and that's why it would be a good time to learn best practices with the above-mentioned tools.

However, when one is trying to squeeze out the last bit of performance out of the application, one is rarely a purist. When you learn more about Scala, compare the purist code to, say, the internals of Apache Spark - they use while loops instead of for comprehensions (or map/flatMap etc.) in many places for performance reasons. The code may look awful at times and a purist would probably get a heart attack, but there's a specific reason for it - the designers knew Scala well enough to themselves be purists, but chose to do otherwise for specific reasons that took priority. I think we need "liberal religions" - it's good to be a purist 99% of the time, but when the cost is way too high and you really know why you're transgressing a rule and what the consequences are, try to consider alternatives. That said, like Travis mentioned, for beginners purism is good because they need to learn what good practices are that work in the majority of cases, and you can then decide to write non-purist code only when there are extenuating circumstances :)