# Grunt installation

Tags: angularjs, node.js, grunt-contrib-jshint

I am building a application with angularjs with a server, when building the backend, it is told to install grunt-contrib-jshint. I have installed grunt to my project but I have no idea why do I have to install grunt-contrib-jshint.

Answer (score 1):

`grunt-contrib-jshint` is used for linting your JavaScript files.
Since you are using angularJs so most probably you need it.

Answer (score 0):

[`grunt-contrib-jshint`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) will validate (aka lint) your JavaScript files with JSHint.

**[Linting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting)** will analyse your code for any potential errors.

Make sure when you install it that you save it to the `package.json` file by either installing it with the `npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev` command or adding the package name and version directly to the file. If you don't do this, other developers will not have a reference to this dependency when they checkout the project. [See more about Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started).

```
devDependencies": {
  "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~1.0.0"
}
```

You will also have to set it up in your `Gruntfile.js` to lint your JavaScript files.

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.initConfig({
  jshint: {
    beforeconcat: ['src/foo.js', 'src/bar.js'],
    afterconcat: ['dist/output.js']
  }
});
```