# Why are single quotes more commonly used in JS files in the last couple of years?

Tags: javascript, string, double-quotes, lint, single-quotes

Why is there a trend for people to use single quotes `'` around `string` instead of double quotes `"` when writing [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)?  Are there any [minifcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) or [linting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting) tools that follow the [java](/questions/tagged/java) / [c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) convention of having double quotes around `string` and single quotes around single `char` and use that for better minification / lint checking? Or visa versa?  Is it a hold over from [php](/questions/tagged/php) or [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) where double quoted strings are more expensive to execute that single quoted strings?

I have found that using double quotes generally tend to create files that [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) better (for transmission over the wire) because the double quotes show up more often, which is better for [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Comment: People are strange creatures - that's one of the things that does not have any rational reason behind it.

Comment: "because the double quotes show up more often" --- that is arguable: `var foo = 'bar';`. In this JS there are 2 single quotes and 0 double quotes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript.

Comment: If you are using double quotes everywhere, vs. single quotes everywhere, why would "double quotes show up more often"?

Comment: @torazaburo , let say I used single quotes everywhere.  As some point I would need to use them around an [tag:html] fragment which includes a lot of double quoted attributes. So now I have mostly single quotes and a bunch of double quotes.  If I switched it the other way and used all double quotes except for the [tag:html] fragment which includes a lot of double quoted attributes, then I would have 2 single quotes and and all - 2 double quotes.

Comment: @Eric so if it works for you and saves 10 bytes after compression - use it.

Comment: Personally I use single quotes for strings that the computer knows about, and double quotes for human-oriented strings, but that's just me.

Comment: "and use that for better handling / checking" --- what does it mean?

Comment: @zerkms , updated the question.

Comment: `"` and `'` both occupy one character. So from minification perspective they are identical. And linters check as per how you configure them, that's the point of linters.

Answer (score 6):

Using single quotes in JS is a convention followed so as to allow a JavaScript string to contain double quotes used (conventionally) in HTML.

Comment: "to save double quotes" --- only in companies, that have monthly quotes on quotes.

Comment: @zerkms, sorry I had just edited out that colloquialism before seeing your comment.

Comment: And maybe the choice of using " for HTML and ' for JS is based on a desire to use single quotes in PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs

Comment: but why use it for strings which do not contain [tag:HTML]?

Comment: @Eric, Consistency makes it a simple convention.

Answer (score 1):

Many code conventions defined by e.g. [JsHint](http://jshint.com/) or [JsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) use single quotes (instead of double quotes) by default.