# Parsing JSON with PHP array/object confusion

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am trying to parse [this JSON data to print on a fanpage I am working on](http://live.nhl.com/GameData/SeasonSchedule-20152016.json).
If you look at that JSON link, you will see that the structure is `[{key:value,key:value,key:value}]`. I recently learned how to parse JSON with a slightly different structure like [this JSON file](http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/playerstatsline/20152016/2/SJS/iphone/playerstatsline.json), where the data structure is `{"identifier":[{key:value,value,value,value,value}{key:value,value...}]}`

Here is my code I am attempting:(I have tried about 10 variations of this with explodes for the commas too)

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://live.nhl.com/GameData/SeasonSchedule-20152016.json');

$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($json as $d){
   $estTime = $d['est'];
     echo $estTime;
?>
```

As I said, I had  some success with that other structure of JSON I linked by doing this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/playerstatsline/20152016/2/SJS/iphone/playerstatsline.json');

$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$skaterData = $json['skaterData'];
$goalieData = $json['goalieData'];

foreach($skaterData as $d){
    $stats = explode(',', $d['data']);
    $number = $stats[0];
        $position = $stats[1];
        $name = $stats[2];
        $gp = $stats[3];
        $goals = $stats[4];
        $assists = $stats[5];
        $points = $stats[6];
        $plsmns = $stats[7];
        $pim = $stats[8];
        $shots = $stats[9];
        $toi = $stats[10];
        $pp = $stats[11];
        $sh = $stats[12];
        $gwg = $stats[13];
        $ot = $stats[14];
```

Edit: [JSON data successfully parsed](http://sjsharktank.com/schedule.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your code is that you are missing the closing curly bracket to your `foreach`.

I would strongly recommend paying attention to the error messages you get, often they will let you easily solve the problem. If your server does not display them in the browser (this is usually a good thing on live sites), you will find them in an error log somewhere on the server.

Additionally you may want to use a proper editor with linting ([what is linting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting)), which would probably have immediately notified you of this omission one way or another. One such free tool is [Atom](http://atom.io).

Comment: Very embarrassing, I was spending so much time on everything else the entire time...Thank you anyways. I use Notepad++ atm

Comment: Unsurprinsingly it is working now haha. Sorry to waste your time. Please don't down vote me! [link](http://52.4.65.161/final_project/schedule.php)