# Can Sublime text build/compile real time (like xcode) as I type codes so it can show my code errors?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there way to have sublime text to build/compile real time as I type code so it can show my code errors if there's any? xcode has this feature.

for example, if i'm writing in a ruby file and in the first line i type:

```
print(hello)
```

and as i enter to the second line, sublime will tell me there's an undeclared variable "hello" in the first line?

Comment: You can try using [**SublimeLinter**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter) along with a [**Ruby Plugin**](https://packagecontrol.io/search/SublimeLinter%20Ruby).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not specific to the build/compilation process. What you're really looking for is [linting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting).

You can use [SublimeLinter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter) coupled with [SublimeLinter-ruby](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-ruby) for ruby linting. There are also [many more packages](https://packagecontrol.io/search/sublimelinter) available for linting other languages at packagecontrol.io.