# Why no "unreachable" statement error/warning shown in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am coming from a Java background. In java if I have a method like below:

```
public static String foo()
 {
     return "foo";
     System.out.println("x");
 }
```

I will get Compilation error :

```
error: unreachable statement
         System.out.println("x");
```

Now I understand that JS,and Java is totally different language. But I wanted to be sure, if what I understood is correct.

Following code works, fine without any error, warning (I read that in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return), we do get warning)

```js
"use strict";
function createIncrementor() {
    console.log('Logging before return .. ' );
    return 3;
    console.log('Logging.. after return' );
}
var inc = createIncrementor();
console.log(inc);
```

`console.log('Logging.. after return' );` is ignored, without Warning/Error or so in Normal run. I saw that ESlint has a rule to check this.

So question is :

Is this expected or I need to enable some setting/config (use strict didn't do anything though)? To check such errors, what is the recommendation? Always use ESLint?

Comment: put the "use strict" inside the function

Comment: @Sergio That won't change anything.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't care that your code is bad. Not only that, there are some legitimate, albeit questionable, cases where you may want to define something after a `return`. See: [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Comment: In a nutshell: Javascript doesn't do these kinds of checks, most likely because it's impractical for an interpreted language vs. a compiled language.

Comment: javascript looks for return statement in a function once it's executed the rest of the lines are ignored following it, But in java you will get a compile time error

Comment: Thanks all, James. @deceze et al I guess I ,missed the fact that its an interpreted language. And once return is interpreted, it won't care.

Comment: This is definitely expected behaviour, console.log() is just another function that due to an early return doesnt get executed. similar to `if (true) : return true; else : return false`

Comment: @Optional Interpreted doesn't mean that the source is read and executed line by line. There is a compilation phase and Javascript *could* do these kinds of checks. It's just that they take time, time that an interpreted language doesn't have if it's trying to run as fast as possible.

Comment: Offcourse yes @deceze, I just read about hoisting too as James pointed.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Not saying that you should, but you could "return" early when you are developing/testing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java that has build in static checks for code - think `FindBugs` - JavaScript relies on third party modules to accomplish [code linting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting) .

See how to [disallow unreachable code using ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unreachable) - one of the popular Javascript linting tools. A common practice is to set up linting with your code editor so that you can see errors it throws upon save.

Comment: Thanks,  I already mentioned about ESLint in question. So it's basically code analysis.

Comment: Yes, its basically code analysis, unfortunately not built into javascript