# How to force Webpack 3 to throw TypeScript errors?

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
// index.ts

let a = 1;
a.map();
```

Webpack doesn't throw this TS error about method "map" on type "number.
**Do you know how check these errors automatically during webpack build?**

Can't find anything on the internet.

Previously I saw this: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/376414/7276837/840b4dec-e8da-11e4-8362-c44f531d8cd9.png

How can I get the same output of webpack (TS errors) using webpack 3?

TypeScript thinks it's ok (any valid JS is also valid TypeScript), so, any project could be bundled with any JS error.

If I'm running tsc app/index.ts then I see the error:
app/index.ts(8,3): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'number'.

So, TypeScript compiler throws the error, but webpack (ts-loader I think) ignores it.

I'm using webpack 3.8.1

Here is config:

```
let path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    entry: path.resolve('app/index.ts'),

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'app.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.ts'],
        alias: {
            vue: path.resolve('node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js'),
            app: path.resolve('app')
        }
    },

    module:{
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx$/, use: 'ts-loader' },
            { test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader' },
            { test: /\.pug$/, use: 'pug-loader' }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve('app/index.pug'),
            cache: false
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        })
    ]

};
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

do you ever heard about [linting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting)? [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-loader)'s the loader for tslint for webpack

Comment: Linting is not checking types.
If you'll use tslint it won't be an error because syntactically it's ok.

Comment: The same, look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/yakimchuk/83c65f5043ab588e75e43545177d5838

Comment: Also, if I remove .ts loaders, then build also successfull.

Comment: // tslint errors are displayed by default as warnings 
    // set emitErrors to true to display them as errors 
    `emitErrors: true`,
    
    // tslint does not interrupt the compilation by default 
    // if you want any file with tslint errors to fail 
    // set failOnHint to true 
    `failOnHint: true`,

Comment: I found error. Pattern /\.tsx$/ was incorrect (I took it from repository).