# Error deploying with firebase on npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I have a fresh install of firebase tools (following this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)) and I'm trying to upload my first firebase function. I get this issue with the hello-world example that they initialise when you run firebase init (The only set up the functions CLI feature during the init)

If I replace `$RESOURCE_DIR` in `firebase.json` with my functions folder it works, but of course that Is bad practice and I'd like to find a proper `$RESOURCE_DIR` replacement that works.

```
PS D:\workspace\firebase-functions> firebase deploy

    === Deploying to 'newagent-5221d'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint
npm ERR! path D:\workspace\firebase-functions\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\workspace\firebase-functions\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dtlut\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-19T15_57_22_990Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238
```

Comment: Could you outline the exact series of steps you take to reproduce this, starting with the moment you run `firebase init`?

Comment: I tried it after just init and after uncommenting the hello world code. Both gave this issue. But the accepted answer solves it.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Try to replace $RESOURCE_DIR with %RESOURCE_DIR% in your `firebase.json` file.

**Multi platform solution**

As seen on [this post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/822#issuecomment-406754186) let's summarize the configuration for the different platforms you are running on:

Linux

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
]
```

PowerShell

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix $Env:RESOURCE_DIR run lint"
]
```

Cmd.exe

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint"
]
```

Comment: @DaanLuttik Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows

Comment: Note that this is a workaround, it's not a solution.  This won't be helpful for teams that work across platforms, as they will each have to maintain their own copy of a file that normally belongs in source control.  I've raised this issue internally with the Firebase team, and things make change here in the future.

Comment: Yeah I noticed. But for me at least its fine. It'd would be nice if there was a cross-platform solution

Comment: The file to be edited here is of course _package,json_ in the root folder of your  local firebase project

Comment: @matthiku Nope, it's `firebase.json` one level up.

Answer (score 56):

It wants to lint your cloud functions, meaning it will check your code for obvious errors like a compiled language would throw errors at compile time.

It's not necessary, you can always remove it by going into firebase.json and updating functions.predeploy to be an empty array.

```
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [],
    "source": "functions" 
  }
```

[What is "Linting"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting)

Comment: i have tried all of the above replacements,but sometimes it showed an error while deploying single functions without replacing existing function,so inside `firebase.json` file i replaced all codes with this>>>  `{}` it worked for me,

Comment: Linting is there for a reason. It may reduce the risk of buggy code resulting in high bills (infinite loops, promises that aren't resolved,...). The solution from Inzamam Malik seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: Thanks! removing predeploy command worked.

Answer (score 35):

you can simply make your firebase.json file like this:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ run lint",
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

what I'm doing is replace $RESOURCE_DIR with hard coded path of function folder
itis working nice for me

Comment: Worth pointing out my `firebase.json` only contained the first line (`... lint",`, but replacing `\"$RESOURCE_DIR\"` with `./functions/` in that line resolved the issue anyway.

Comment: this is very useful

Answer (score 13):

**SUMMARIZING**

1. Install ESLint locally to add "devDependencies" to **package.json**. Run:

   ```
    `npm install eslint --save-dev`
   ```
2. Workaround for Windows as stated above. Change **firebase.json**:

   ```
    `npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint` to `npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint`
   ```
3. Optionally, add the following to **package.json**:

   ```
    "scripts": { "lint": "eslint"} or "scripts": { "lint": "eslint.js"}
   ```

Answer (score 6):

locate the firebase.json file 
and then change these lines

```
"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
```

to

```
"npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
"npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
```

it'll work

Comment: This worked for me too but I don't understand why it works. Please explain.

Comment: actually in windows it doesnt understands the '$' symbol it is only meant for linux systems but windows understands the ' %' symbol

Answer (score 2):

Modify in firebase.json from "`npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint`" to "`npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint`"

Answer (score 2):

side note, if you're using `yarn` (and not `npm`), you need to specify `--cwd` param (instead of `--prefix`)

`firebase.json` example:

```json
{
  ...
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "yarn --cwd \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" lint",
      "yarn --cwd \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" build"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was my node version. I got this error after installing packages with the wrong node version. I ran `yarn` setup with node 16 but my project uses node 14. I switched to node 14 before trying to deploy and received this error. I tried the fixes mentioned here and finally realized what my problem was. This is one of those errors which is disinformative...

Answer (score 0):

**This one should solve the issue without workaround**

`npm install -g git://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#master`

please try this installation again in ur project folder it should solve the issue.

Comment: I can confirm latest version hasn't fixed the issue, just installed on a fresh machine 
 (W10, Powershell) and encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

It is working my cloud function deploy successfully

```
"functions": {
"predeploy": [
  "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
  "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
],`enter code here`
"source": "functions"
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous suggestions worked for me. So I deleted the function part of the firebase.json file as in below by only keeping the hosting part. Then, I deployed the app successfully without functions.

Then, I cd into functions from the terminal and deployed the functions by using `firebase deploy --only` functions

```
{

  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is there are some errors in the code for example, I got this error message

```
  55:47  error  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='  eqeqeq
  69:47  error  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='  eqeqeq
```

After I fixed and deploy again and it work.
[this attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFV6O.png)

Answer (score 0):

My approach to fixing this issue was to remove the period (`.`) after the `eslint` in `package.json`.

So, change:

```json
 "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint.",
 }
```

To:

```json
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone out there, you might as well run `npm install` first just to make sure everything is in place before deploying. Worked for me