# Firebase Function Deployment issue: package.json not found in %RESOURCE_DIR%

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I having problem of deploying Firebase Cloud Functions.

**Steps to reproduce**

- firebase init
- select function only
- select Firebase Project
- select Javascript
- use ESLint
- install dependencies with npm now
- Run firebase deploy

**Expected Result**

Expecting firebase-tools to deploy the cloud functions.

**Actual Result**

Receive the following error message:

```
λ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to '<projects>'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! path ...path\firebaseFunction\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...path\firebaseFunction\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ...path\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-17T10_02_45_577Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238
```

I have tried googled it and follow the solutions on below link but it doesn't work to me:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/610

Please help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Try replacing the string `"$RESOURCE_DIR"` with `"%RESOURCE_DIR%"` in your "firebase.json" file.

Now run the deploy command again. It worked for me.

Explanation: This fix is for Windows because `%RESOURCE_DIR%` will be recognized as an environment variable only by Windows command-line interpreters. As an ultimate consequence, the project isn't cross-platform anymore, as mentioned in the answer of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345315/error-deploying-with-firebase-on-npm-prefix-resource-dir-run-lint).

Comment: Thank you so much, it just worked! Do you know any particular reason for this? Is this because of difference in file referencing in DOS and *nix?

Comment: Yes, In Dos variables begin with %, while for *nix, they begin with $.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** In firebase.json file

try and replace `$RESOURCE_DIR`with `%RESOURCE_DIR%`
   and

`"npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint" to "npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint"`

(the above one just worked around )

**2.** `npm install -g git://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#master`

please try this installation again in ur project folder it should solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem just remove the predeploy from firebase.json file and it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're either using an old version of the Firebase CLI, or a project that was initialized with an old version.  The cleanest thing to do would be to upgrade your CLI:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

And create a whole new project from scratch with `firebase init`.  Then, reconstruct your new project with the code from the old project.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
"functions": {
  "predeploy": [
    "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
    "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
  ]
}
```

to

```
"functions": {
  "predeploy": [
    "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
    "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Step1: open firebase.json you will show this JSON file

`"functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
}`

Step2: Delete "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint", and "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"

`"functions": {
    "predeploy": []
 }`

Now deploy, it works fine