# Firebase CLI doesn't work when deploying fucntions. Error: HTTP Error: 404, Method not found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to follow the tutorial from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

and I'm getting the error `HTTP Error: 404, Method not found.`
I can't find anything online about why this is happening or how to get the logs for this.

I've tried all the fixes from here, [Error deploying with firebase on npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345315/error-deploying-with-firebase-on-npm-prefix-resource-dir-run-lint) and none of them works for me.
PS: I'm running this on Cloud Shell.

Comment: `Where` are you getting this error?

Comment: "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]

Comment: @hkchakladarOn the cloud shell, when I run the command firebase deploy.

Answer (score 1):

When I had the same error, I resolved it by running `firebase login`.

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it clear this was an answer, not a related question.  Answers that start off with *I had the same error.* tend to get flagged as non-answers.  If my change was in error, feel free to revert.