# when i run this command "firebase deploy --only functions" it show me errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-functions, mern, firebase-tools

I want to use Firebase Database as i am developing Amazon Clone , so when i run this command "firebase deploy --only functions" to deploy my backend on firebase but i am getting errors like,

node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT

```
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
```

code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
spawnargs: []
}
what should i do,
i have blaze account also on firebase.

i have tried to restart firebase server, checked codes but i dont't know what is going wrong

Comment: Please go through  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345315/error-deploying-with-firebase-on-npm-prefix-resource-dir-run-lint).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I ran these command in the functions directory:

1. `npm run lint -- --fix`
2. `npm run build`
3. `firebase deploy --only functions`