# WordPress: How to loop post type to custom dashboard menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom WordPress dashboard menu and I want to display post list there. I try to display with loop inside a function, but getting error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'`

Here is my code:

```
function _submenu_cb() {
    $args = array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'pubish' );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        echo '<h1>'.the_title().'</h1>';
    }
}
```

How to fix this?. Is it possible to display the post list in custom dashboard menu by looping the post inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be editing code in an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) with the appropriate [linters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting) installed, as they will help diagnose snytax errors like these.

If you take a look at the entire error, it will tell you what line it's on as well. I just pasted it into my editor and you can see right where the error is.

[image: Screenshot of IDE]

Looking backwards, it appears you didn't close your `while` loop. Note the code you're using is the [Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for your `while` loop, but standard curly bracket syntax for your `if` statement. You need to add an `endwhile;` after your `echo` and before the curly bracket closing your `if` statement:

```
function _submenu_cb() {
    $args = array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'pubish' );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            // Do Stuff Here, like output the title
        endwhile;
    }
}
```

Note that you also have a WordPress specific error in your `echo`. [`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) by default actually outputs the title. You're effectively conflating `the_title()` and `[`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title). You'll want to use one or the other. Either:

```
echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
```

or drop the echo and use:

```
the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
```