# pylint protection against self-assignment

Tags: python, pylint

I have this test file:

```py
"""module docstring"""


class Aclass:
    """class docstring"""

    def __init__(self, attr=None, attr2=None):
        self.attr = attr
        self.attr2 = attr2

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'instance_of the Aclass {self.attr}.'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'The A with: {self.attr}.'


def init_a():
    """function docstring"""
    a_inst = Aclass()
    attr = 1
    attr2 = 2
    a_inst.attr2 = attr2
    # should be: a_inst.attr = attr, but have a typo
    attr = attr
```

and I inspect it using pylint, and the output shows everything is alright.

```sh
$ pylint test.py 

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

Based on the [linting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting), i expect the flag about suspicious usage in software language, because i don't know when this code `a=1; a=a` can be useful.
And I want to see some warning, for example:  unused variable or self-assignment  etc. Is there way using the pylint? (I know about Pycharm and sonarqube). Example of the [sonar rules](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/findbugs:SA_LOCAL_SELF_ASSIGNMENT?layout=false).

```
public void foo() {
    int x = 3;
    x = x;
}

Such assignments are useless, and may indicate a logic error or typo.
```

details about the `pylint`

```
pylint 2.3.1
astroid 2.2.5
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  5 2019, 22:05:54) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
```

**UPDATE** Has added to the version [pylint 2.4](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.4.html)

Comment: It sounds to me as though the crux of your question is "is there a situation in which `a=a` might not have no effect?". I'm fairly sure you can manage something like this by making a gigantic mess with module loaders and descriptors. It'll probably take me quite a while to actually write something that works. Would some code that causes `a=a` to have a side effect answer your question?

Comment: no my question is how i can run pylint to catch the warning the with the same rule as in the example from sonar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've took a look at Pylint rules and I did not find anything to help you solve this issue. What I did find is that you can write your own checker and make pylint using it :

`$ pylint yourpieceofcode.py --load-plugins=checker`

checker.py :

```py
from pylint.checkers import BaseChecker
from pylint.interfaces import IAstroidChecker


class SelfAssignChecker(BaseChecker):
    __implements__ = IAstroidChecker

    name = 'self-assign-returns'
    priority = -1
    msgs = {
        'W5555': (
            'Self assignment (%s).',
            'self-assign',
            'useless assignment.'
        ),
    }

    def visit_assign(self, node):
        names = []
        for child in node.get_children():
            if not hasattr(child, 'name'):
                return
            if child.name not in names:
                names.append(child.name)
            else:
                self.add_message("self-assign", node=node, args=child.name)


def register(linter):
    linter.register_checker(SelfAssignChecker(linter))
```

Doc [here](http://pylint.pycqa.org/projects/astroid/en/latest/api/index.html) ! :)

Tested on your file `test.py`. Output :

```
$ pylint --load-plugins=checker test.py
************* Module test
test.py:25:0: C0304: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
test.py:25:4: W5555: Self assignment (attr). (self-assign)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 8.57/10 (previous run: 9.29/10, -0.71)
```

Pylint version :

```
$ pylint --version
pylint 2.3.1
astroid 2.2.5
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0]
```